# What does this mean: 'puts up a poster touting for relief milking work'?

Tags: meaning

> Pip chats to Lilian at The Bull. **Pip puts up a poster touting for
>   relief milking work**, but manages not to let slip about Bridge Farm.
>   When Spencer rings Pip whilst she’s there, Pip tells him all about
>   it.
>  ([thearchers.co.uk](http://www.thearchers.co.uk/en/catch-up))

There are words and phrasal verbs which are unclear to me; I fail to understand the highlighted sentence. Could you provide me the sense of the sentence?

Comment: Try definition 1, fourth example [here](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/poster); definition 2, [here](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/tout); and definition 7, [here](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/relief).

Comment: @StoneyB- My question is whether it should be "*touting relief milking work*." (without the *for*)

Comment: @Jim  Pip is seeking employment, so *for* is called for.

Comment: In future, can you please be more specific about what in the sentence you are confused by. There are many slightly complex parts of the sentence (Pip is a noun and an uncommon short name, "put up" is perhaps a complex verb for a beginner, "touting" is an uncommon verb, "relief" meaning emergency aid is somewhat uncommon, "milk" as a verb might be confusing to a beginner etc etc). Your questions really do need to be **more specific** and not just a highlighted sentence from a paragraph saying that you don't understand it.

Comment: @Listen, is *Pip* a common name? I have never heard of it from Anglophones, although Italians have *Pippo* as an abbreviated form of *Filippo*, and we also have *Peppe*, which is an abbreviated form of *Giuseppe*.

Comment: @Matt, I have just seen you comment. Yes I agree. *Pip* should be an uncommon name.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: It's an uncommon and old-fashioned short for "Phillip". The protagonist of Great Expectations (Charles Dickens) for example is called Pip.

Comment: @StoneyB- Thanks. I don't *ever* use *touting* **for** so it's an odd construction for me. I'd tend to say, "Pip put up a poster *touting himself* as a relief milking worker." Or reword it altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent sentence to the one highlighted is

> "Pip *(name - commonly short for Philip)* is placing an advert *(a poster)* which is looking for workers who can provide supplementary, temporary or emergency work extracting the white liquid known as milk from animals (milking can be done to a variety of animals, but the typical implication is milking cows)*".

Edit: As FumbleFingers rightly notes - "touting for work" typically means "advertising one's own labor" rather than "seeking the labor of others" - however in this case the sentence uses the phrase "touting for work" in the context of Pip putting up a poster - something that is more usually used to advertise job vacancies rather than candidates.

Which one of these is correct would normally be determined from the wider context of the passage.

Comment: ***Or*** Pip's poster may be touting for ***work for himself*** (and possibly others who are seeking employment). I don't follow The Archers, so I don't know which interpretation is more credible, but without more context, both are perfectly valid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You're absolutely right. I don't listen to The Archers either, so I have no idea which interpretation was the intended one.

Comment: You might argue any such posters would *in general* tend to be seeking *workers*, rather than *work*. But the text does say *touting for **work***, which leans more the other way. Whatever - I'll upvote if you mention the alternative reading of *tout* in the answer text itself.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this sentence literally involves milking a cow (or other mammal), or _milking_ (defrauding) some _relief_ (assistance) fund or program. Neither meaning makes a lot of sense, but the first could be read that the milker is spelling (relieving, temporarily substituting for) another worker, while the second sounds risky (publicly advertising to commit a crime). More context would be helpful (is Bridge **Farm** sufficient?).

Answer (score 3):

[Tout](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/tout) is a verb that means, "to try to persuade people to buy your goods or services, especially by going to them and asking them directly."

It can be transitive or intransitive. in the first case, *tout* is not followed by *for*; the direct object is the good or service that person is trying to sell. In the second case, *tout* is not followed by a direct object.
Take "the problem of unlicensed taxi drivers touting for business at airports" as example. The phrase doesn't explicitly say which service the taxi drivers are trying to sell, but since the  phrase says "for business" it's implicit the service is taking people somewhere, which is what taxi drivers do as business.